# Remove unexpected content on a website

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

While following a [tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html) on building a Ruby-on-Rails blogging website, I'm running into some unexpected results. The project so far is stored on https://github.com/khpeek/jumpstart-blogger.

The main page is an "Articles" page, which looks like this:

[image]

So far, so good (except for the somewhat curious position of the "Create a New Article" button, which used to be directly below the articles).

The appearance of "All Articles" is governed by `app/views/articles/index.html.erb`, which reads

```
<h1>All Articles</h1>

<ul id="articles">
  <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to article.title, article_path(article), class: 'article_title' %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= link_to "Create a New Article", new_article_path, class: "new_article" %>
```

The `h1` heading is the first thing in the .html.erb file, and also the first thing that appears on the web page.

However, if I click on an article link, say "Article with Ruby Tag", I see the page below:

[image]

Besides the desired box with the article, tags, and comments, there are also two submit buttons and "<< Back to Articles List" buttons which are neither desired nor expected.

The appearance of this page is governed, as I understand it, by `app/views/articles/show.html.erb`, which reads

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>
<p>
  Tags:
  <% @article.tags.each do |tag| %>
    <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag) %>
  <% end %>
</p>
<% if @article.image.exists? %>
  <p><%= image_tag @article.image.url %></p>
<% end %>
<p><%= @article.body %></p>
<h3>Comments (<%= @article.comments.size %>)</h3>
<%= render partial: 'articles/comment', collection: @article.comments %>
<%= render partial: 'comments/form' %>
<%= link_to "<< Back to Articles List", articles_path %>
<% if logged_in? %>
  <%= link_to "delete", article_path(@article), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Really delete the article?"} %>
  <%= link_to "edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
<% end %>
```

The first line in this file is the `h1` header, but the 'unexpected' contents seems to come before that. So I'm having trouble seeing where to start to remove this content. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dealing with layout Rails' concept. [Read this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Anyway, you probably have a layout file in `app/views/layouts`.

Answer (score 0):

check your application.html.erb in layouts folder.. it is rendering in header on some condition